# Is it possible to have an Excel formula dependent on value input?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

Is it possible to have Cell G24 recognize the number in D24, and do its math depending on the size of the number, using the in Cells B37 through B42?

I have a basic spreadsheet for cataloging sales and costs. Our cost is dependent on the system size.

I'd like to have Excel know what cell (I have a list of costs currently) to multiple from depending on the system size I input.

What I'd like:

Row D, (cell D24 for this individual sale) is where I enter the "System Size".

I'd like Row G (cell G24 for this sale) to calculate the cost based on the size in D24.

Further down the page I have my tiered costs listed:

- Cell B37 has our cost for systems sizes between 3.0 and 3.99
- Cell B38 has our cost for systems sizes between 4.0 and 4.99
- Cell B39 has our cost for systems sizes between 5.0 and 5.99
- Cell B40 has our cost for systems sizes between 6.0 and 7.99
- Cell B41 has our cost for systems sizes between 8.0 and 9.99
- Cell B42 has our cost for systems sizes 10.0 or above

Is it possible to have Cell G24 recognize the number in D24, and do its math depending on the size of the number, using Cells B37 through B42?

Comment: Yes it is possible.  What gave you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

This is the non-macro way.

```
=IF((A1>=3) AND (A1<=3.99),B37,IF((A1>=4) AND (A1<=4.99),B38,IF((A1>=5) AND (A1<=5.99),B39,IF((A1>=6) AND (A1<=7.99),B40,IF((A1>=8) AND  (A1<=9.99),B41,IF((A1>=10),B42,"not found"))))))
```

You can put formulas in place of b38 through b42

Comment: That looks odd, unless Excel has changed after version 2007.

Comment: @Hannu   It may look odd, but it 100% valid, I tested it.  I was writing things like this back in the 90's with office 95 and 97.  I wrote things way more complicated that were 2x and 3x longer.  This is grade school work compared to what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Type in the system size limits in cells A37 to A42, as in:

```
3
4
5
6
8
10
```

Then `=VLOOKUP(D24;$A$37:$B$42;2;1)` will pick out the relevant system cost factor from B37 to B42.

Check the Excel help for `VLOOKUP() function` for understanding the innards of this.


*Save this as "filename.csv", then OPEN it in Excel or LibreOffice:*

```
Sys Size,,,Cost factor
9.99,,,=VLOOKUP(A2;$A$5:$B$10;2;1)

Size,Sys cost
3,1
4,2
5,3
6,4
8,5
10,6
```